# Truetime iOS Framework is giving Timeout error

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am using TrueTime Framework to get exact time independent of Device time. 
but for couple of weeks I am observing that, on initialisation

```
let client = TrueTimeClient.sharedInstance
client.start()
client.fetchFirstIfNeeded(success: { (time) in
    print(time.now())
}) { (myError) in
    print(myError.localizedDescription)
}
```

it gives Timeout error

> com.instacart.TrueTimeErrorDomain Code=2 "The connection timed out."

I have tried it by

- Creating new Objc and Swift projects
- Cloning their Git Repo and ran their sample project
- Getting the framework from branch 4.2.0

but in each case the outcome is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a different ntp server. Check if it also timeouts. This can be done by specifying the array when calling `start`

EDIT: Issue was caused by blocked port. Try using a different network

Comment: your suggestion is logical but it is not working either. I guess it is an issue cause by the Framework itself

Comment: hmm. I am using this repo also and it works for me. The difference is I am using the 5.0 release though. But upon inspecting the changes, there should have been no problem whether it is 4.2 or 5.0 version. 

Here is my snippet (on 5.0)


`let client = TrueTimeClient.sharedInstance`
`client.start(pool: ["time.apple.com"], port: 123)`

Could it be the ntp port is blocked in your network?

Comment: Man you are right, The NTP port was blocked at my network. Please Update your answer and add this to your answer then i will accept it.